# SQL Server 2008 - Calculate min and max dates of contribution amounts made in chronological order

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have some customer financial data as shown below and can't figure out how to display the start and end contribution dates for each regular amount that has been paid.  I'm using SQL Server 2008. My source data appears below.

```
Cust  Contrib_Date  Amount
----  ------------  ------
100   2013-01-01    500.00
100   2013-02-01    500.00
100   2013-03-02    500.00
100   2013-04-01    500.00
100   2013-05-05    600.00
100   2013-06-06    600.00
100   2013-07-05    600.00
100   2013-09-10    500.00
100   2013-10-10    500.00
100   2013-11-10    500.00
100   2013-12-11    500.00
200   2010-01-01    100.00
200   2010-02-02    100.00
200   2010-03-09    300.00
```

Here is what I'm trying to get from the output.

```
Cust  Start_Date  End_Date    Amount 
----  ----------  ----------  ------ 
100   2013-01-01  2013-04-01  500.00  
100   2013-05-05  2013-07-05  600.00  
100   2013-09-10  2013-12-11  500.00  
200   2010-01-01  2010-02-02  100.00  
200   2010-03-09  2010-03-09  300.00
```

The customer is making regular monthly contributions into an account. The amounts stay the same over each period (we have 3 for Cust = 100, i.e. 1st period 500.00 was paid, 2nd period 600.00 and 3rd period was back to 500.00) but the contribution dates may vary slightly by a couple of days due to weekends, public holidays, etc. as demonstrated above. So, I need to loop through the data, find the min and max contribution dates in chronological order for each amount for every customer and when I come across a different amount start the process again. There will be many customers that this would need to be done for.

I'm relatively OK with SQL but can't figure a way how to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?  Can anyone help? I've used cursors before but not that often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  y.Cust, 
        MIN(y.Contrib_Date) AS FromDate, 
        MAX(y.Contrib_Date) AS ToDate, 
        y.Amount
FROM (
    SELECT  x.Cust, x.Contrib_Date, x.Amount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cust ORDER BY x.Contrib_Date ASC) 
            - 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cust ORDER BY x.Amount ASC) AS GroupID
    FROM    @Contrib x
) y
GROUP BY y.Cust, y.GroupID, y.Amount
ORDER BY y.Cust, FromDate;
```

Ouput:

```
Cust FromDate   ToDate     Amount
---- ---------- ---------- ------
100  2013-01-01 2013-04-01 500.00
100  2013-05-05 2013-07-05 600.00
100  2013-09-10 2013-12-11 500.00
200  2010-01-01 2010-02-02 100.00
200  2010-03-09 2010-03-09 300.00
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30697)</kbd>

Comment: This almost works. The problem is that the GroupID for Cust = 200 groups together 2 different amounts (100.00 and 300.00) and uses the earliest Contrib_Date for Amount = 100.00 as the FromDate for Amount = 300.00 but with the correct oldest Contrib_Date for Amount = 300.00. So, in the output there should be 2 amounts (100.00 and 300.00) but I only get output for 300.00.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic!!  I've tried it and it works.  Thank you very much Bogdan.  I'll be able to sleep now.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: +1 That is a very nice trick to get the sequences of payments split out correctly. And thanks for putting the data into a fiddle. (@Fred_Scuttle: It is ideal to provide that sort of sample data load when asking a question rather than depending on the community to do it for each answer.)